# Android setting Custom Adapter to viewPager

Tags: android, view, adapter, pager

I created a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter. I want to contain it inside a view pager and display other things (title, etc) in the xml layout.

So right now I can get it to work without a viewPager with the following code in the onCreate method:

```
AppAdapter adapter = new AppAdapter(this,appinfo);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But I get an error when I try the following:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); //says custom adapter can't be applied, should be normal adapter
```

xml part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#EEEEEE"
android:padding="5dip"
android:id="@+id/lay">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I'm pretty sure there's a simple fix to this, without creating a custom adapter as well. Please let me know your opinion from here

Comment: If you are set adapter to `ViewPager` then it should be extends with `PagerAdapter` or `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

The `PagerAdapter` used by the `ViewPager` is completely different from the `Adapter` used by subclasses of `AdapterView` (wich include `ListView`, `Spinner`, `Gridview`, ... but not the  `ViewPager`).

The only implementations provided are `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. You can write your own, but it's a bit more complex than a *normal* adapter.

By the way each, of these adapters exist in 2 versions, one in the v13 compat lib (for native fragments):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

and one in the v4 compat lib (for compat fragments) :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html